# Google app engine Error "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to access google app engine https://appengine.google.com/ from my newly created google apps account.

It shows an error "This webpage has a redirect loop" after login to my new google apps account. I am not sure how to fix this, i tried clearing cache & cookies, but it repeats the same.

I am not sure if it is the right place to ask the question. Please let me know if there is any different forum to post this question.

Please let me know if you need my email address.

Thanks,

Ramesh.V

Comment: What browser? Try Chrome, it seems to always work with Google sites.

Comment: Tried chrome, firefox, IE, nothing works, even tried on a brand new system (where i never logged in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's the browser. Have you tried to authenticate in another browser? Or do you have a automatic login plug-in as last pass f. e. that's causing the loop?
There are also other people with this issue [1].

[1] http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8142

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. It seems to be an issue with Federated Login. When I switched the app from Federated Login to Google Account API everything worked properly.

Federated login is still experimental and should not be used in a production environment in my view.

Cheers,
Kjartan S.